# power BI embedded : Error retrieving Access token

Tags: powerbi-embedded

When i try to integrate power BI report in my app i have this error:

Error retrieving Access token
AADSTS650: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '45ea49-48eb-4c4-a4ca-97dd84f5d85' named 'PBI Emb APP'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.

Can someone explain the problem.

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must log into Azure portal, go to `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations`, select your app, click `View API permissions`, and then grant admin consent by clicking the button at the bottom:

[image]

If you don't have access to the portal, or the button is disabled, you must ask your admin to do it for you.

This happens because you are logging in in an unattended way. If it was an interactive login, you will get a prompt to consent, but when doing it the way you do now, there is no way for prompting you to give the consent or decline it.